# About time complexity of algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity, computer-science

What is the **time complexity** of the problem below.

```
int j=1;
while(j<n){
  j+=log(j+5);
}
```

Comment: what's `n`? is it 0 or 1? easy going. is it greater than 1? well, it depends on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By expanding the first three terms of the sum:

[image]

You can see that it's just a sum of iterations of `log(log(j))`'s.
Since O(j) >> O(log(j)), it follows that O(log(j)) >> O(log(log(j)); the first term therefore overshadows all of the other terms.

The sum is therefore O(log(j)), which means the time complexity is

[image].

Numerical tests show that this is actually O(n^0.82...). [image]

Comment: I didn't think log() was logarithm, I was thinking it was just some random function the poster didn't define.

Comment: @Hardy `log()` is almost _always_ defined as a natural logarithm in programming languages' math libraries

Comment: Ya, I was thinking this was just a general programming question, not a math/comp sci question. I see the tags now though.

Comment: @Hardy well this _is_ a comp-sci question, but again `log` is the standard name (in both contexts) for natural logarithms

Comment: Sorry, I miss "+" before "=". And it has been changed now.

Comment: Is it means that the more specific time complexity is O( n/log(6) )(not a standard expression, but make it more clear), 'cause either log(log(j+5)+5) or log(log(log(j+5)+5)+5) are nearly equal to log(6), which is as known as log(j+5). Is it right?

Comment: @Alahaga not log(6) - approximate log(j + 5) as log(j) -> O(log(log(j + 5) + 5)) = O(log(log(j))) << O(log(j)), so only the first term dominates

Answer (score 0):

With the edited code (`+=` instead of `=`), I'll conjecture that the asymptotic time complexity of this code (assuming that `log()` and other elementary operations take constant time) is Θ(*n* / log *n*).

It's easy to show that the loop takes at least *n* / log(*n*+5) = *n* / (log *n* × log 5) iterations to complete, since it's counting up to *n*, and each iteration increments the counter by an amount strictly less than log(*n*+5).  Thus, the asymptotic time complexity is *at least* Ω(*n* / log *n*).

Showing that it's also O(*n* / log *n*), and thus Θ(*n* / log *n*), seems a bit trickier.  Basically, my argument is that, for sufficiently large *n*, incrementing the counter *j* from exp(*k*) up to exp(*k*+1) takes on the order of *C* × exp(*k*) / *k* iterations (for a constant *C* ≈ (1 − exp(−1)) / 5, if I'm not mistaken).  Letting *h* = ceil(log(*n*)), incrementing the counter from 1 to *n* thus takes at most

*T* = *C* × ( exp(*h*) / *h* + exp(*h*−1) / (*h*−1) + exp(*h*−2) / (*h*−2) + … + exp(1) / 1 )

iterations.  For large *n* (and thus *h*), the leading exp(*h*) / *h* term should dominate the rest, such that *T* ≤ *C*<sub>2</sub> × exp(*h*) / *h* for some constant *C*<sub>2</sub>, and thus the loop should run in O(exp(*h*) / *h*) = O(*n* / log *n*) time.

That said, I admit that this is just a proof sketch, and there might be gaps or errors in my argument.  In particular, I have not actually determined an upper bound for the constant(?) *C*<sub>2</sub>.  (*C*<sub>2</sub> = *C* × *h* would obviously satisfy the inequality, but would only yield an O(*n*) upper bound on the runtime; *C*<sub>2</sub> = *C* / (1 − exp(−1)) would give the desired bound, but is obviously too low.)  Thus, I cannot completely rule out the possibility that the actual time complexity might be (very slightly) higher.